# Prolog Counter Problem

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a procedure `order(List,Result)` that has a `List` as input and returns a list `Result` of ordered pairs such that:

- the first element of the ordered pair is the position of the pair in the list, and
- the second element of the ordered pair is the element from List n the corresponding             position.

Example:

if `List = [a,b,c,d]`, the procedure order(List,Result) outputs the list:
`Result = [(1,a), (2,b),(3,c),(4,d)]`.

I am struggling with the counter for the position of the pair in the list. I have made attempts such as:

```
increment(Accum,Total):-
        Total is Accum + 1.
order([],[]).
order([Head|Tail],Result):-
        order(Tail, NewTail),
        NewCount is Count + 1,
        increment(NewCount,Count),
        Result = [(Count,Head)|NewTail].
```

Please help anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two clauses: `NewCount is Count + 1` and `increment(NewCount,Count)` basically have the same meaning. You didn't make clear that `Count` is an input variable and it has a base case of `1`, so Prolog didn't know where to start unifying values for it. For example, you should use `Count` as an input argument as follows (it doesn't change much if compared with your version):

```
order([],[], _).
order([Head|Tail],[(Count,Head)|NewTail], Count):-
        NewCount is Count + 1,
        order(Tail, NewTail, NewCount).

order(List, Result ):- order(List, Result, 1).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using `findall/3` then this is probably the simplest solution:

```
order(List, Result) :-
    findall(Index-Elem, nth1(Index, List, Elem), Result).
```

Note that here the key-value pairs are represented using the term `-/2`, which is how pairs are usually represented in Prolog, e.g. this is what `keysort/2` expects.

Answer (score 0):

```
order(List,Result) :-
        findall((N,E),(
                    append(L0,[E|_],List),
                    length([_|L0],N)),
                Result).
```